# C++ can't create vector of user defined class

Tags: c++, class, vector

I'm trying to create a vector of a class I just set up and I keep getting errors.  Can anyone give me some advice?  Here's my relevant code:

```
class process{
    public:
        enum state {New,Ready,Running,Waiting,IO,Terminated};
        double CPUburst[MAXCPUBURSTS];
        double IOburst[MAXCPUBURSTS-1];
        int nCPUbursts; // The number of CPU bursts this process actually uses
        int priority, type; // Not always used
        int currentBurst; // Indicates which of the series of bursts is currently being handled
};

vector<process> processTable;
```

the error I'm getting is:

`"template argument for 'template<class _Alloc> class std::allocator' uses local type 'main(int, 
     char**)::process*'"`

Comment: Did you accidently define the class inside of a main method?

Comment: @Antimony I'm not sure why it would matter. I had no problem defining both the class, and the vector, in my `main()` method.

Comment: http://ideone.com/5s5ZOe works fine, so I believe Antimony is correct.

Comment: I did define it inside of the main method.  Seems to have fixed my problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have defined `class process` inside `main`.

From the standard (older)

> A local type, a type with no linkage, an unnamed type or a type compounded from any of these types shall not be used as a template-argument for a template type-parameter.

However, this has changed in c++11 and later.

So, define the class in global scope or use a compiler (or enable) which supports this feature. In g++, you can enable this with `-std=c++0x` or `-std=c++11` depending on the version.

Comment: That's not what the *current* Standard says.  That rule, found in section 14.3.1 of C++03, simply no longer exists today.

Answer (score 2):

Antimony has decoded the relevant details from your code that you didn't bother to mention.

The fix is to enable C++11 support in your compiler (typically `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`).  C++03 didn't permit using local classes as template arguments.  C++11 does.

Comment: +1 I honestly never knew that was even previously restricted. I knew local *functors* were not allowed, but never knew about local classes in general. Wish I could toss an upvote to Antimony too. Thanks guys.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Local functors *were* allowed, but you couldn't do much with them, because of this restriction.

Comment: I never knew about them! I guess there's a reason for that, seeing as how I wouldn't have been able to use them anyway since local functors is probably exactly my use-case.